# Laravel 5.4 PHPunit testing Unreachable field (used name/id attirbute)

Tags: php, phpunit, laravel-5.4, domcrawler

I'm testing Laravel according to Laracast/Integreted **following exactly as name attribute shown** [there](https://github.com/laracasts/Integrated/wiki/Learn-the-API#typetext-selector-or-filltext-selector). And one form in per page.

I have some unit test on a form where first two field is reached but on third field which is a textarea with name="input". Here is the view html

```html
<form method="POST" action="/problem/add">
          {{ csrf_field() }}

          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Problem Title</label>
                  <input name="title" type="text" class="form-control pull-right" style="width: 100%;" placeholder="Give a title">
                  </input>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- /.col -->

              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Select a contest</label>
                  <select name="contest_id" class="form-control" data-placeholder="Select a Contest" style="width: 100%;">

                  @foreach($contests as $contest)
                    @if(isset($addToContest) && $contest==$addToContest)
                      <option selected="selected" value="{{ $contest->id }}">{{ $contest->title }}</option>
                    @else
                      <option value="{{ $contest->id }}">{{ $contest->title }}</option>
                    @endif

                  @endforeach

                  </select>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
              <!-- /.col -->


              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Problem Description:</label>
                    <textarea name="description" class="textarea description" placeholder="Place some Description" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;"></textarea>
                </div>
                <!-- /.form group -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.col-->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Sample Input:</label>
                    <textarea id="input" name="input" class="textarea input" placeholder="Place Sample Input" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;"></textarea>
                </div>
                <!-- /.form group -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.col-->

              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group"> 
                  <label>Sample Output:</label>
                    <textarea id="output" name="output" class="textarea output" placeholder="Place Sample Output" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;"></textarea>
                </div>
                <!-- /.form group -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.col-->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->

            <div class="box-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn bg-olive btn-flat ">Create</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn bg-orange btn-flat ">Cancel</button>
            </div>

            </div>

          </form>
```

While running phpunit code

```
public function testCreateContest()
{
    $this->visit('/admin_login')
        ->type('admin@admin.com', 'email')
        ->type('123456', 'password')
        ->press('Login')
        ->see('Admin')
        ->onPage('/admin_home')
        ->visit('/create_contest')
        ->see('Create New Contest')
        ->type('Contest Test', 'title')
        ->type('21/06/2017 0:00 - 25/06/2017 23:59','start_end_time')
        ->type('Test Contest Description','description')
        ->press('Create')
        ->see('Add Problem')
        ->submitForm('Create', [
            'title' => 'Test Problem',
            'description' => 'Test Problem Description',
            'input' => 'Test Input', //Here the test fails
            'output' => 'Test Output',

            ])
        ->see('Problem added to the contest');
}
```

I get

```
    There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Unit\CreateContestTest::testCreateContest
InvalidArgumentException: Unreachable field "input"

D:\SoftProjects\CodeCuet\vendor\symfony\dom-crawler\Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\FormFieldRegistry.php:89
D:\SoftProjects\CodeCuet\vendor\symfony\dom-crawler\Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\FormFieldRegistry.php:126
D:\SoftProjects\CodeCuet\vendor\symfony\dom-crawler\Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Form.php:76
D:\SoftProjects\CodeCuet\vendor\laracasts\integrated\src\Extensions\IntegrationTrait.php:380
D:\SoftProjects\CodeCuet\vendor\laracasts\integrated\src\Extensions\Goutte.php:52
D:\SoftProjects\CodeCuet\tests\Unit\CreateContestTest.php:36
```

I have **also used all possible selector in type() like id,class** but nothing can reach last two textarea fields. Please guide me with any solution or explanation of this problem.